# User-defined text fields in django admin

Tags: python, database, django, database-design, relational-database

Django (and database) newbie here.

I'm trying to figure out a way to enable the creation of n custom text fields for a table (let's call it Book) using the admin interface. I would like a way for the user to define new text fields through the admin interface (instead of defining fields like CustomField1, CustomField2, etc, through a model followed by running manage.py syncdb).

Ultimately, I would want to create a separate table called CustomFields. The django admin user (who is not a programmer), would go and enter the custom text fields in this table (e.g. pubdate, isbn, country). Then, when doing data entry for a Book, they would hit "+" for every custom field they wanted, have them available in a dropdown, and add accompanying text for the custom field. The text entered for each field is specific to the parent Book.

Any suggestions? I have a feeling there's a simple solution that I'm somehow not grasping here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you might run into problems is because Django will not recreate tables or columns based on changing model declarations. This means you're unable to add fields to a table at run-time without running the generated sql on your database manually. What you'll need, instead, is a way of defining custom fields, and linking them to your model.

What I'd suggest is the following:

```
class CustomField(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Book(models.Model):
    ... fields

class CustomValue(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(CustomField)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

The validation on the above is fairly non-existant, and this doesn't allow you to define required custom fields for each model, but you should be able to come up with that part if you need it later on.

```
# taken and modified from django online tutorial
class CustomValueInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CustomValue
    extra = 3

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
       # your fields in here
    ]
    inlines = [CustomValueInline]

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

This will allow users to select up to 3 custom fields and values directly, with the option to add more if they wish.

Edit: Changed the answer to reflect further information in comments.

Comment: When I follow your example, I get <class 'bookcms.bookedit.models.CustomValue'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'bookcms.bookedit.models.Book'>

Comment: Hmm, that might be due to Book containing a ManyToMany relation instead of the CustomValue containing a foreign key back to Book. CustomValue should not be applied to multiple Books in hindsight. Put a book = models.ForeignKey(Book) into CustomValue, move CustomValue below Book, and see how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It seems to be working fine. Incidentally, what would you suggest for re-ordering these custom values?

Comment: If you need to order them, you'll either have to order based on a current field, or have an order column which someone will need to maintain. That should be on the Custom Field model.

Answer (score 0):

For the beginning you can create one model for the book and one for the text field, both connected through a [foreign key relation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey). You can easily administrate this then through [django's inline admins](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects), which will enable you to add more text fields!

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class TextField(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)

# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from models import TextField, Book

class TextAdmin(admin.TabularInline):

    model = TextField

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TextAdmin]

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

Comment: Are you certain that the register line reads admin.site.register(BookAdmin)? Because when I run that, I get an error ('MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable). If I change the line to "admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)", I get another error ('model' is a required attribute of 'BookAdmin.inlines[0]').

Comment: I removed the Meta class of TextAdmin and set the attribute for the TextAdmin object directly, and that seems to fix the error. Thanks for your help. I'm still looking to improve it by having a dropdown of custom fieldnames (defined in another table by the user) next to the text field, however.